# Problemas al realizar una query

Tags: python, django

estoy realizando una aplicación la cual obtiene datos y después los muestra por medio de gráficos, el problema es que estoy realizando una consulta para saber cuando desarrolladores pertenecen a un proyecto, pero me arroja un error disiento que el objeto ManyToManyDescriptor no cuenta con el atributo filter.

Mi vista:

```
class ProjectTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def count_developer(self):
        projects = Project.objects.all()
        for project in projects:
            developers = Developer.project_set.filter(project=project).count()
            print(developers)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['projects'] = Project.objects.all()
        context['developers'] = self.count_developer()

        return context
```

Este es mi modelo proyecto:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('approver', 'Aprovado'),
        ('process', 'En Proceso'),
        ('inactive', 'Inactivo'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Nombre')
    developer = models.ManyToManyField(Developer, verbose_name='Desarrollador')
    visibility = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Visibilidad')
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='Estatus')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de Creacion')
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True, verbose_name='Fecha de Actualizacion')
```

Y este es mi modelo desarrollador:

```
class Developer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de Creacion')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te da error ya que estas tratando de acceder a la relación atraves del modelo, debe ser una instancia en especifica, algo así:

```
Developer.objects.get(...).project_set.filter(project=project).count()
```

Necesitamos un tipo de dato que nos lleve a obtener una instancia especifica del modelo `Developer`, pero no tiene sentido hacer esto por como estas extendiendo el contexto de la vista y por como es el método `count_developer`...
mas bien pienso que quieres listar todos los proyectos existentes y saber cuantos desarrolladores pertenecen a estos, y así mostrarlos en el template.

Entonces, para obtener los registros seria así:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Project.objects.annotate(Count('developer'))
```

Cada instancia tendrá un atributo llamado `developer__count`, que sera el numero de desarrolladores que pertenecen a esta.

Entonces tu vista debería ser algo así:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class ProjectTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['projects'] = Project.objects.annotate(Count('developer'))

        return context
```

Pero te recomiendo usar una vista `ListView` y simplemente sobrescribir el metodo `get_queryset`.

Y podrás mostrar los datos en el template, algo así:

```
{% for p in projects %}
    ...
    <!-- demas datos -->
    <span>Desarroladores de este proyecto: {{ p.developer__count }}</span> 
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: muchas gracias me has ayudado mucho, estaba haciendo algo sin sentido con el contexto, pero te agredesco seguire inventigando mas sobre el manejo de queryset, porque esta funcionalidad no sabia que la tenia